# GMIC FILTER OVERLAY?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYhDis257gc In the link, it shows the GMIC FILTER OVERLAY effect... What is that? I mean, what does it do, and how can I use it? Does it come with blender, and if not, how can I enable it?
I've searched for YouTube videos on the subject, but nothing appears... I'll try Blend Swap later, if no one can answer me here. I have several renders I'd like to apply this to, so any information is appreciated!

Comment: This appears to an effect in GIMP

Comment: Gimp? How do I use that?

Comment: It is a free open source image editing program. Look up GMIC OVERLAY on google, the effect should come up. Download GIMP [**here**](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE Joey, we hope you stick around to contribute and learn!  We do like to restrict our scope to things that directly relate to Blender though, hence this question was closed.  But [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/gmic-is-an-incredibly-powerful-filtering-system-for-gimp/) is a link to an article about G'MIC, it seems to be a filter for [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/).